# If $f$ is smooth and we write with Taylor's formula $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+...+\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)x^k+h(x)x^k$ is then also $h$ a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth and write with Taylor's formula $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+...+\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)x^k+h(x)x^k$$ is then also $h$ a smooth function?
Obviously $$h(x)=\frac{1}{x^k}\left(f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-...-\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)x^k\right)$$
is smooth for $x\neq 0$. I can only show that $h$ is once-differentiable at $0$. (Arguing similar as in the solution to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998034/showing-differentiability-of-gx-begincases-fracfxx-textx-neq0). If needed I can provide the details.) Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: This may be of [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3406636/121671) with little effort you may modify the argument to suit your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder is
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+...+\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)x^k+ R_k(x)
$$
with
$$
 R_k(x) = \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^x (x-t)^k f^{(k+1)}(t) \, dt
= \frac{x^k}{k!} \int_0^1 (1-s)^k f^{(k+1)}(xs) \, ds
$$
so that your $h(x)$ has the representation
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^1 (1-s)^k f^{(k+1)}(xs) \, ds \, .
$$
It follows that if $f$ is “smooth” (in the sense of “infinitely differentiable”) then the same holds for $h$. More generally, if $f^{(k+1)}$ exists and is continuous then $h$ is continuous, and if $f^{(k+1+l)}$ exists and is continuous then $h$ is $l$ times continuously differentiable.